# Default as "no alert" when create event from email

Tags: mail.app, email, calendar, notifications, alert

I love creating events in my calendar from emails.

But I recently missed an event because, when created from an email, the event default alert is "None", and I did not change it manually.

Is it possible to change the default event alert for event created from the calendar to "10 minutes before the event"?

Answer (score 1):

In your calendar application, under Calendar -> Preferences -> Alerts you should be able to set the default alerts for Events. Changing this should apply to events created from within mail too.

Comment: Thanks @moneyt. Unfortunately, it seems that Mail override this. If Mail creates an event for which the alert setting is "None", then on my side, I receive no alert even when all calendars alert preferences are set to "Events: 10 minutes before".

Comment: @MartinVanderLinden Hmmm, it works locally for me. The two things I would check are which account you have selected in the calendar preferences window, and also note that events on a particular day but with no time in the mail message will trigger an all day even, which has a different default reminder setting in that preferences window.